# AngularJS Filter in MattLewis Angular Bootstrap Calendar

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, calendar

I want to achieve a searching for event inside the MattLewis Angular Bootstrap Calendar from this https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar

I already set up everything, the filters work but it just give me a bunch of error that causes my other functions did't work well.

Here is code for calendar

**HTML**

```
<mwl-calendar events="events | filter:{title:listView}"
                              view="calendarView"
                              view-title="calendarTitle"
                              view-date="date"
                              on-event-click="eventClicked(calendarEvent)"
                              on-event-times-changed="eventTimesChanged(calendarEvent); calendarEvent.startsAt = calendarNewEventStart; calendarEvent.endsAt = calendarNewEventEnd"
                              edit-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\'></i>'"
                              delete-event-html="'<i class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove\'></i>'"
                              on-edit-event-click="eventEdited(calendarEvent)"
                              on-delete-event-click="eventDeleted(calendarEvent)"
                              cell-is-open="isCellOpen"
                              day-view-start="06:00"
                              day-view-end="22:00"
                              day-view-split="30"
                              cell-modifier="modifyCell(calendarCell)"
                              on-view-change-click="false">
                </mwl-calendar>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.events = [
           {
               title: 'An event',
               type: 'warning',
               startsAt: moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').add(8, 'hours').toDate(),
               endsAt: moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'week').add(9, 'hours').toDate(),
               draggable: true,
               resizable: true
           }, {
               title: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i> <span class="text-primary">Another event</span>, with a <i>html</i> title',
               type: 'info',
               startsAt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
               endsAt: moment().add(5, 'days').toDate(),
               draggable: true,
               resizable: true
           }, {
               title: 'This is a really long event title that occurs on every year',
               type: 'important',
               startsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
               endsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(19, 'hours').toDate(),
               recursOn: 'year',
               draggable: true,
               resizable: true
           }
        ];
```

this is the filter i've tried

```
events="events | filter:{title:listView}
```

but sad to say it just give me a bunch of errors

Here is the error
[image]

is there any other solution to what i want to achieve. I tried custome filters like this

```
app.filter('searching', function() {
    return function(items, word) {
        var filtered = [];

        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            if(item.indexOf(word) !== -1){
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        });
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

but did't work too. The error is in `indexOf` not recognize as function

Comment: without  `| filter:{title:listView}` is it working fine? Have you tested it?

Comment: yes without filter it works fine but i need some filtering